# Why was Shenron afraid of Bills?

Tags: dragon-ball-z, dragon-ball-series, dragon-ball-super

Having the ability to grant all wishes and being powerful why does Shenron have to be afraid of Bills in the movie **Dragon Ball Z: Battle Of The Gods**?

Answer (score 7):

If you don't recall the Dragons that are created by the Dragonballs are only as powerful as the person who created them.  This means that Shenron is not all powerful and cannot grant a wish outside of the power of their creator, an example would be wishing to destroy Freiza when Kami was the creator.  Dragons from the Dragonballs can grant any wish as long as it's within their creator's power... this means a being more powerful than the creator of them cannot be destroyed by the Dragon and the Dragon can be destroyed by that being.

Dragonball Wiki Excerpt:

> Shenron can bestow any wish as long as it does not exceed the power of
>   his creator, who must be still alive (i.e. Kami/Piccolo or Dende).

During Battle of the Gods this means that Dende is the current creator of the Dragonballs, which means that any being more powerful than Dende could defeat Shenron...

Answer (score 3):

Shenron actually does not have the power to grant all wishes.  He can't bring you back from the dead twice, he can't wish the Saiyans away in the first saga.

He can do things that no one else is able to do, but he's not actually all powerful.

And apparently he's less powerful than Bills, and he knows it.

Comment: i wonder if the Namik's dragon is more powerful than bills since he can bring a person back as many times as he wants

Comment: +1 All the dragons and all the kai's fear Bills. He is indeed the most strongest being ever. The only weird thing is that Bills regards Frieza as the next most powerful after himself. What about Cell, Buu, Pycon, Supreme Kai etc ..... Gotta love them movie plotholes

Comment: @krikara well, buu was really really ancient, cell was brand new, and pycon was from a different corner of the universe

Comment: @SamIam The point is that there are many different characters that are all stronger than Frieza, yet Bills has not noticed any of them. The excuses for Bills not knowing any of them start becoming paper thin.

Comment: @krikara Frankly, I think it would be a plot hole if Bills DID know about the androids and cell, If you remember back to the beginning of the series Frieza **was** the strongest known being at the time, and apparently that was the case for more than 20 years.  That Bills didn't know about the androids and buu probably makes more sense than the other way around.

Comment: @SamIam Okay, but I'm not talking about JUST Cell and Buu. How about the Supreme Kai, or Bibibi/Bobidi? How about all the various characters from the other movies? People like Pycon come a dime a dozen; just because he is on the other side of the universe doesn't mean Bills should not know of his strength. If I am not mistaken, Bills is able to locate strong beings and then challenge them.

Comment: He should know Buu at least since Buu has been around since Bills' time.

Comment: @Jack Bills more than likely knows kid Buu since that is his original form and is much strong than Fat Buu. Kid Buu has was trapped in Fat Buu. So Bills doesn't see him as being one of the most powerful

Answer (score 0):

In Dragon Ball, Shenron was once killed by King Piccolo. If someone evil but way less stronger than Beerus can kill Shenron, it makes sense Shenron to be afraid of Bills the god of destruction and most powerful being in the universe after Wiss